# Dropping the last bit

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

Given the value: 0x9e9090ab (10011110100100001001000010101011)

I want to parse the value ignoring the 32nd bit such that I end up with:
0x1e9090ab (00011110100100001001000010101011)

My attempts at doing this via a bitmask (0x9e9090ab & ~0x10000000) don't seem to be working and result in a signed negative number.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose I could just as easily  (0x9e9090ab << 1) >> 1, but hoppefully someone has a better solution.

Comment: It must be 0x80000000 et not 0x10000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the bitmask `~0x80000000` instead of `~0x10000000`, since `0x10000000` refers to the 29th bit. Example:

```
var result = 0x9e9090ab & ~0x80000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it's easier to think about this way:

`0x9e9090ab & 0x7FFFFFFF`

You can compare using node:

```
> (0xFFFFFFFF).toString(2)
'11111111111111111111111111111111'
> (0x7FFFFFFF).toString(2)
'1111111111111111111111111111111'
```